# Problemas para arrancar un sitio web con IIS en Window 10

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

hice una aplicación web con Net Core 5, la cual funciona sin problemas en mi maquina de Desarrollo, al pasar la aplicación al entorno de producción, me tira el error que se ve en la imagen.

El sitio esta montado en una maquina virtual con Windows 10 dentro de un Windows Server 2000 (Ignoro el porque se hizo asi).
La carpeta de la aplicacion esta en la raiz de c:\procesotela; agregue el usuario IIS_IUSRS con todos los permisos, sin embargo me marca error en el archivo web.config, en el tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebProcesoTela.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: de35c59b-548d-4b33-9773-53317bfddd37-->
```

[image: Error de inicio]

En el IIS al intentar cargar los Modulos, sale este error.

[image: Error al cargar los modulos]

¿Alguna sugerencia, para encontrar el error?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, incluye los detalles de la configuración que realizaste para añadir esa webapp al IIS.

Comment: Intenta eliminar esta parte `forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"`, también incluye cómo generaste el proyecto y si tienes instalado el framework o si tienes el framework de manera independiente en una carpeta. Por curiosidad, ¿Windows Server 2000?

Comment: @fredyfx para añadir la web, solo puse los datos de la pantalla "Agregar sitio web", Nombre del sitio: procesotela; Grupo de aplicaciones: DefaultAppPool (tambien intente con un nuevo grupo); Ruta de acceso fisica: C:\procesotela; Puerto: 9095 y nada mas.
Asi lo hice en mi maquina y funciona perfecto.

Comment: El proyecto lo genere con VS2022, no he revisado si el FrameWork esta instalado.
Si, es Windows Server 2000 y ahi montaron una MV con Windows 10, ignoro totalmente por que, de eso se encargan otras personas.

Comment: Ya revise y si esta instalado el Framework 4.7 de .Net

Comment: ¿Seguro que es Windows Server 2000? Hay 22 años de diferencia. Por otro lado, si estás usando NetCore, revisa si hay alguna carpeta que contenga los runtimes porque si estás usando Full Net Framework 4.7 y quieres ejecutar NetCore, te va a dar errores. Dato adicional, averigua por qué tienen una máquina virtual para montar un IIS Express en un Windows Server obsoleto, o bien se ganan un premio por la innovación o una alta posibilidad de un hackeo brutal por falta de actualización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@freyfx gracias por tu ayuda.

Cometí un error de principiante, no habia instalado los runtimes de Net Core 5, y por eso tiraba el error.

Los instale y funciono de inmediato.

Comment: Dejo para completar la respuesta donde se decarga el runtime de [ASP.NET Core 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0) y aclarar que la [NET5 ya no tiene soporte desde el 10/Mayo/2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) para tener en cuenta de planificar update a NET6 que es LTS (soporte de largo plazo como 3.1) y que para cualquier version en Windows debemos  instalar Hosting Bundle (que incluye .NET Runtime y compatibilidad con IIS)